# PL0 interpreter - write string on the screen

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter

I would like to ask for a help with this task:
I am studying subject Formal Languages and Compilers and I have to solve this exercise:

*In PL0, the instruction WRI 0 0 displays on the screen the character whose ASCII value is on top of the stack, and reduces the top of the stack pointer by 1. Suppose the stack is stored string of characters (think of how to save). Write a sequence of instructions that any such string displays on the screen.*

Could someone please give me advice, how to do it? Basicaly, I understand, how the PL0 works - what does the instructions in PL0 mean, but I have no idea how to deal with this exercise.
Thank You very much

Comment: See [help], point #3: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Answer (score 0):

My idea is as follows:

**Saving a string of characters:**

The user is prompted to enter the number of characters of the string. Then is a while cycle running  and for each iteration, the user is prompted to enter the ASCII value of the character.

**Write the string on console:**

Again, while cycle is running and through each iteraton the instruction WRI 0 0 writes on the console top char from the stack. The problem is that the string is rotated course (eg. the specified sequence of characters A, B, C will be written on the console as CBA).

Unfortunately I have no idea of a way to turn the string. I will be grateful for any advice.
Thank you.

```
              INT 0 5                           
              &ECHO Enter length of a string:
              REA 0 0
              STO 0 3
              LIT 0 1
              STO 0 4
@loop_read    LOD 0 4
              LOD 0 3
              OPR 0 13
              JMC 0 @end_read
              &ECHO Enter the ASCII code of a char:
              REA 0 0
              LOD 0 4
              LIT 0 1
              OPR 0 2
              STO 0 4
              JMP 0 @loop_read
@end_read     LIT 0 1
              STO 0 4
@loop_write   LOD 0 4
              LOD 0 3
              OPR 0 13
              JMC 0 @end_write 
              WRI 0 0
              LOD 0 4
              LIT 0 1
              OPR 0 2
              STO 0 4 
              JMP 0 @loop_write
@end_write     RET 0 0
```